# Error when adding value to array

Tags: python, arrays, debugging, append

with open('file00.txt') as f00:
            for line in f00:
                farr=array.append(float(line))
                print "farr= ",farr

i get:

`farr=array.append(float(line))`

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'append'`

does anyone know why I get this? do I have to import something? am I doing it completely wrong?

thanks

Comment: Where is your array defined? And what is `array`? Is it a list?

Comment: as u might see, i am a complete newb at programming & python, so im not entirely sure. Im just doing it by example from others in here. I might have missed some things.

am i defining an array wrong? i assumed here that `farr=array.append(float(line))` is how you define one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to do something like this instead:

```
values = []
with open('file00.txt') as f00:
    for line in f00:
        value = float(line)
        values.append(value)
        print "farr= ", value
```

That way the `values` list will contain all values.

Answer (score 1):

To append to an array, you must create the array (as an instance of the `array.array` type with the appropriate type code), giving it a name, and call `append` on that name - that is, on the **instance**, definitely **not** on the module.

So, for example:

```
>>> import array
>>> x = array.array('d')  # array of double-precision floats
>>> x.append(1.23)
>>> x
array('d', [1.23])
>>>
```

and so on.  Of course, you could also use a `list` instead of the `array.array('d')` (precious if you want to append values of different types, or of non-elementary types), but the principles are identical: you make an **instance** of `list`, then call `append` on the **instance** (through the name you gave it on creation), definitely *not* on any module!